# How to remove /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules CentOS

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a server that we are testing a stretched network failover with VMware Recover Point.  When the server moves over to the alternate site, the MAC address changes causing my network interface (eth0) to become `eth1` due to the regeneration of the `70-persistent-net.rules` file creating the new eth0 with a new MAC Address.

I would like to write a script at boot up that removes this file so `udev` creates it new, but am having difficulty knowing where to place it.  I tried `/etc/rc1.d/S25_70`, which is above the `/etc/rc1.d/S26_udev-post`, but it isn't working.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to have two rules defining `eth0` in the `70-persistent-net.rules` file, one each for the relevant MAC addresses in each server.  This version of the file should be the same on **both** servers.

When booted on server1, server1's MAC address gets eth0.

When booted on server2, server2's MAC address gets eth0.

e.g.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="11:11:11:11:11:11", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="22:22:22:22:22:22", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Change `"11:11:11:11:11:11"` and `"22:22:22:22:22:22"` to match the hardware in your servers.

---

BTW, if using `systemd`, have two files in /etc/systemd/network, one for each matching MAC address.  e.g.

/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0-1.link:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=11:11:11:11:11:11

[Link]
Name=eth0
```

/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0-2.link:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=22:22:22:22:22:22

[Link]
Name=eth0
```

From `man 5 systemd.network`:

> [MATCH] SECTION OPTIONS
>
> The network file contains a `[Match]` section, which determines if a given network file may be applied to a given device; and a `[Network]` section specifying how the device should be configured.
>
> The first (in lexical order) of the network files that matches a given device is applied, all later files are ignored, even if they match as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying the start-up script for `udev` to delete the file `70-persistent-net.rules` before it does anything else.

Or add a custom hook/script to your initramfs (generation).